# Struct with one field (i.e. integer) - do you still need to override GetHashCode, Equals, etc?

Tags: c#, performance, struct, hashset, gethashcode

Often when there is anyone talking about structs, it is recommended that you override `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, etc.

Is this also necessary if you have a `struct` with just a *single integer* (or any other *simple value type*)?

Say i.e.:

```
public struct LolCatId
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public LolCatId(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

When using in `HashSets` etc - is there anything that needs to be thought of or will this work perfectly how you expect in all cases performance-wise?

Comment: Yes, you'd better *override* https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/07/17/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Make it an answer. That's a great resource.

Comment: You could just do `public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better *override* `Equals` and `GetHashCode` since default equliaty members for value types are often *reflection-based* (and that's why can be *slow*).

And some default `Equals` implementations are quite *weird*, e.g.:

```
  // Wrong Equals optimization demo: 
  // .Net (4.7) doesn't use reflection here but compare bytes 
  // and this decision is incorrect in the context
  struct MyDemo {
    public double x;
  }
```

...

```
  byte[] bits = BitConverter.GetBytes(double.NaN);

  bits[1] = 42;

  // a holds "standard" NaN
  MyDemo a = new MyDemo() { x = double.NaN };
  // b holds "modified" NaN
  MyDemo b = new MyDemo() { x = BitConverter.ToDouble(bits, 0)};

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    $"Are structs equal? {(a.Equals(b) ? "Yes" : "No")}",
    $"Are fields equal?  {(a.x.Equals(b.x) ? "Yes" : "No")}"));
```

Outcome:

```
Are structs equal? No
Are fields equal?  Yes
```

For details see

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/07/17/performance-implications-of-default-struct-equality-in-c/

Let's be on the *safe side* especially when both methods can be *easily implemented*, e.g. in your case:

```
public struct LolCatId {
  public int Id { get; }

  public LolCatId(int id) {
    Id = id;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() => Id;

  public override bool Equals(object obj) => 
    obj is LolCatId other ? other.Id == Id : false;
}
```